# I can't set custom style to antd Date Picker in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I want to set the custom style to antd DatePicker but it just doesn't work. Some styling work and some are not.

**JSX**

```
 <div >
        <DatePicker
          defaultValue={moment(date ? date : new Date(), dateFormat)}
          defaultPickerValue={moment(date ? date : new Date(), dateFormat)}
          format={dateFormat}
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
          allowClear={false}
          style={{
            height: "53px",
            width: "155px",
            border: "1px solid blue",
            borderRadius: "0px",
            cursor: "pointer",
            fontSize: "17px",
            margin: "0px",
            padding: "0px"
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

Expected behaviour:

[image: I want this]

Actual behaviour:

[image: I don't want this]

It currently shrinks the height. I don't want this.

I want the date picker to take full width and height. Also, How can I remove default border style in antd date picker? is It possible to remove that calendar icon?

I will appreciate your reply. thank you.

Comment: @Farhan he said that he is using [ant-design datepicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/)

Comment: @blueseal you can always provide your own version of theme by making custom themes according to your need. This is how all uses all third party readily available components like material design, bootstrap components.

Comment: @vipulpatel can you provide me with some resources or tutorials link so that I can follow them to implement my own custom themes. I belong to android development so I don't have much experience in web. thank you

Comment: @blueseal now every popular library gives the way to theme their components according to clients project requirement . its easy to find. lets say you are using angular material comps. You can follow theme guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `height` and `width` make there CSS value to `auto` and for hiding the calendar icon you just put `suffixIcon` property with `DatePicker` tag.

Please see below code or [LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-80zsw)-

```
<DatePicker
          defaultValue={moment(new Date(), 'DD MMM, YYYY')}
          defaultPickerValue={moment(new Date(), 'DD MMM, YYYY')}
          format={'DD MMM, YYYY'}
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
          allowClear={false}
          suffixIcon
          style={{
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto",
            border: "none",
            borderRadius: "0px",
            cursor: "pointer",
            fontSize: "17px",
            margin: "0px",
            padding: "0px"
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. so nice of you. Your answer is correct. date picker height issue is fixed. The calendar icon is gone. but the border-radius is still there. is it possible to have no border-radius? https://imgur.com/a/o7bv6aK

Comment: What you actually want, to remove border or border-radius. Because your image URL not open. @blueseal

Comment: For removing `border-radius` you can use CSS to style your datepicker `input` field.

Comment: Glad to help you :) @blueseal

Comment: could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/58492391/5124488 . I just can't find out the correct antd classnames for antd `Select` to override custom styles. Someone has already setup a codesandbox.

Answer (score 2):

The css is being applied to the span while it should also be reflected on the input inside, you could write [custom css](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-currying-8xttx) to set style of that input using its selector:

**`custom.css`**

```css
.ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input {
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 53px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. the height is fixed but the icon is still there. Sorry I couldn't accept your answer. is it possible to remove that border-radius? https://imgur.com/a/o7bv6aK

Comment: yes I've updated the codesandbox with the `suffixIcon` property as pointed by shubham

Comment: Thanks to you. all the issues are fixed. the border-radius issue is also solved.

Comment: may I ask a question, how can someone use the correct class names to override default antd styles. like you used```.ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input```, where can I get these class names? did you choose the classname from https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/date-picker/style/Calendar.less ?

Comment: thee only way is to inspect and see the control. custom controls having their own css generally are associated with css classes and rarely they rarely change

Comment: oh I see. I just inspected the date picker and found ```.ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input```. you are very helpful. thank you.

Comment: could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/58492391/5124488 . I just can't find out the correct antd classnames for antd `Select` to override custom styles. Someone has already setup a codesandbox.