# How to set custom style to antd Select?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I want to customise antd `Select`. When a user click on `Select` the antd `Option` should display over antd `Select` instead of displaying beneath the `Select`

antd `Select`: https://ant.design/components/select/

Expected behaviour:[image: I want this][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgR3p.jpg)

Actual behaviour:[image: I don't want this][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs7Qv.jpg)

**JSX**

```
import { FaPlane, FaWater } from "react-icons/fa";

//outside of class
const shipmentType = {
  sea: [
    { name: "FCL", desc: "FULL CONTAINER LOAD" },
    { name: "LCL", desc: "LESS CONTAINER LOAD" }
  ],
  air: [{ name: "AIR", desc: "AIR DELIVERY" }]
};


//inside of class

render(){
       return(
              <Select
              className="container-dropdown"
              onChange={this.onSelectChange}
              defaultValue={
                  <DisplayContainer data={shipmentType.sea[0]} />
              }
              key={ shipmentType.sea[0]}
            >
              <Option value={shipmentType.sea[0].name}>
                <DisplayContainer data={shipmentType.sea[0]} />
              </Option>
              <Option value={shipmentType.sea[1].name}>
                <DisplayContainer data={shipmentType.sea[1]} />
              </Option>
            </Select>
          );
}
```

**DisplayContainer.js component**

```
const DisplayContainer = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "120px",
        height: "45px",
        display: "flex",
        flexFlow: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
      <span
        style={{
          display: "block",
          fontSize: "8px",
          padding: "5px 0px 0px 10px"
        }}
      >
        {data.desc}
      </span>

      <span style={{ padding: "2px 0px 0px 14px" }}>
        {data.name === "AIR" ? <FaPlane /> : <FaWater />}
        <span
          style={{ display: "inline", marginLeft: "14px", fontSize: "16px" }}
        >
          {data.name}
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**App.css**

```
.container-dropdown {
    height: 53px;
    width: 140px;
    border: 0px solid white;
    border-radius: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**custom-antd.css**

```
.ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single {
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
    height: 53px;
}

.ant-select-selection-selected-value {
    height: 53px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.ant-select-selection__rendered {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.ant-select-dropdown-menu.ant-select-dropdown-menu-root.ant-select-dropdown-menu-vertical {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

How can I achieve this? I have already spent hours of time. but I couldn't succeed. I will appreciate you. thank you

Edit 01:

**When a user clicks the `Select` box**

I want the top `Option` (i.e. `FCL`) goes up and cover the `Select` box like this:

[image: I want this]

I don't want both the `Options` (i.e. `FCL` and `LCL`)to be displayed below `Select` box:

[image: I don't want this]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe I have been able to get pretty close to what you are looking to achieve. Below is the updated **custom-antd.css** file.

```
.ant-select-selection-selected-value {
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  height: 53px;
}

.ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single {
  height: 53px;
}

.ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single
  > div
  > div
  > div
  > div
  + div {
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding: 4px 5px 5px 14px !important;
}

.ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single > div > div > div > div {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single[aria-expanded="true"]
  > div
  > div
  > div
  > div {
    margin-top: -10px;
}

 /*style for when the menu is expanded: show shipment description above icon and name*/ 
.ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single[aria-expanded="true"]
    > div
    > div
    > div
    > div
    + div {
       margin-top: -15px;
}
```

The complete code sandbox can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-goldwasser-bk393?fontsize=14).

Essentially what you want to do is use combinators to select the specific `div`'s for the name, the description, etc. which ant design nests pretty deep in their structure.

**EDIT**

In order to get the dropdown menu to display different data based on what is currently selected (show LCL only when FCL is selected, vice versa), you can utilize an handleChange function that filters the original shipment data so it returns everything that is not currently selected (i.e. showing LCL without FCL when FCL is selected). By storing the original shipment data in state, along with a second array (filtered menu data), you can use/update the second array for your selection options.

Here is your state.

```
  this.state = {
     shipmentArr: [],
     shipmentType: {
        sea: [
          { name: "FCL", desc: "FULL CONTAINER LOAD" },
          { name: "LCL", desc: "LESS CONTAINER LOAD" }
        ],
        air: [{ name: "AIR", desc: "AIR DELIVERY" }]
     }
  };
```

Here is the new `handleChange`.

```
handleChange = value => {
   var newShipmentType = this.state.shipmentType.sea.filter(x => {
     return x.name !== value;
   });
   this.setState({
     shipmentArr: newShipmentType
   });
};
```

Here is the `componentDidMount` (utilizing `handleChange`).

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.handleChange(this.state.shipmentType.sea[0].name);
};
```

Below is the updated `Select` component.

```
<Select
    className="container-dropdown"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    open={true} // USE THIS FOR DEBUGGING.
    defaultValue={
      <DisplayContainer data={this.state.shipmentType.sea[0]} />
    }
    key={this.state.shipmentArr[0]}
  >
    {this.state.shipmentArr.map(x => {
      return (
        <Option value={x.name}>
          <DisplayContainer data={x} />
        </Option>
      );
    })}
  </Select>
```

See the full [updated codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-goldwasser-bk393?fontsize=14).

Comment: Please see I have updated the question. I have added two more images. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @blueseal is there any reason you're not using state?

Comment: I'm actually using `state`.

Comment: @blueseal Awesome. I updated the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-fire-9cgup). Essentially you need to change the data you're supplying to the dropdown menu. The data can be changed based on what us currently selected. The updated solution also works with more than two options as it is dynamic.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I wanted. I'm going to accept it. Thank you so much.

Comment: did you inspect `antd` components to get those `antd` class names or is it available in their github repo or something?

Comment: @blueseal no problem. I'm not sure if it's available in the repo. I just inspected them. Ant Design uses a lot of nested `div`'s and `span`'s to it just took some time working my way down the nested elements to the find the ones that needed to be targeted.

Comment: @MattCroak How did you manage to inspect the dropdown? Anytime I try to inspect it in Chrome it closes, whether using keyboard shortcut or mouse. Thanks!!

Comment: @blueseal for the styling I don't think I needed to inspect the open part of the drop down, just the top part. However if you want to further inspect the opened part of the drop down, just give your `Select` component a temporary prop of  `open={true}`. This will force the drop down to remain open while you inspect it. Then remove it when you're done debugging. I added it in the code sandbox and the code in the original answer.

Comment: @MattCroak if you have some spare time, would you mind to answer it https://stackoverflow.com/q/58772432/5124488 ?

Comment: @blueseal I just posted an answer for it :)

Comment: This answer (and question) refer to ant design 3.x. The css in this answer will not work for 4.x

Answer (score 0):

on the version  "antd": "^5.9.3", you can use this css for change select element

```
:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-1ck3jst).ant-select-single:not(.ant-select-customize-input) .ant-select-selector{
  height: 40px !important;
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 02px 5px 10px 0 #9191911f;
  border:1px solid #646cff75;
  background-color:#f6f6f6 ;
}
```