# How to set custom style to antd Rate Component

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

When I mouse over a star in Ant Design's [`Rate`](https://ant.design/components/rate/) component it's size increases and on mouse out it goes back to the original size. This is probably due to an innate `transform: scale(x)` in the component. I want to stop this animation/behaviour of stars if I mouse over them. How can I achieve that? I have tried different `element state` in devtools but failed.

I'm able to set custom `width` and `height` but I can't find something which can stop that animation/transform :/ . [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-https-po46e)

```
.ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-full i svg {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -3.5px;
}
.ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-zero i svg {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -3.5px;
}
.ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-half.ant-rate-star-active i svg {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -3.5px;
}

.ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-full i svg:hover {
  transform: scale(1); //not working
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key classes to isolate here are `.ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-full`, `.ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-zero`, and `.ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-half.ant-rate-star-active` as these correspond to the fully filled, empty, and half filled stars. You're right to assume it was `transform: scale(x);`. With a little testing you can find the right scale value (oddly enough `.91` was the most seamless). I also had to change the `transition` since the root element had some sort of transition where the counter scaling would work but there would be a short period of 'bounce' where it was transitioning from the attempted scale up to the forced scale down.

Here is the update [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wave-n0hq3). Below is the updated CSS.

```
  .ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-full,
  .ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-zero,
  .ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-half.ant-rate-star-active {
      transition: transform 0s;
  }

  .ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-half.ant-rate-star-active:hover {
      transform: scale(0.91);
  }

  .ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-full:hover {
      transform: scale(0.91);
  }

  .ant-rate-star.ant-rate-star-zero:hover {
      transform: scale(0.91);
  }
```

I actually also wrote a blog post a while back where I wrote a [blog post](https://codeburst.io/a-simple-star-rating-system-using-vanilla-js-css-and-html-caf1b3e4d9f1) about my own custom star rating system with vanilla JS, CSS and HTML if you're interested in something a bit more easily customizeable :).

Comment: Thank you. Somehow it's pretty close to what I needed. However, if I set `margin: -3.5px;`, sometimes it doesn't work it still moves if I mouse over them. In my actual project, I need the `margin`. Sometimes, I have to click on one star to see the animation effect. any idea? https://imgur.com/KGlLYVi

Comment: I will definitely check out your blog post :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to complicate the things here. You can simply use fontSize property as follows which will allow you resizing the icon's size -

```
<Rate disabled defaultValue={3} style={{ color: "black", fontSize:10 }} />
```

Comment: thanks, i was wondering how to change the star color. your answer work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can style inline on the component:

```js
<Rate style={{ color: '#00c' }}>
```